# Substitution value dynamically in <h:outputText

Tags: spring, jsf, jstl, spring-webflow

I am trying to dynamically pass a value in h:outputText tag.

The scenario being, I have a properties file with key/value pairs and I m fetching the data from properties file:

Eg:

roles.properites

admin=Administrator
user=User
visitor=Visitor

I now access the code this way `<h:outputText value="#{myRoles.admin}"/>` will display Administrator

Now I have a value dynamically stored in spring conversation scope:

Say {conversationScope.userRole}

I can't invoke the properties file property this way
`<h:outputText value="#{myRoles.conversationScope.userRole}"/>`

How do I pass the conversation scope value as a property of a resource bundle.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Having a resource bundle declared as:

```
<resource-bundle>
   <base-name>anyBaseName</base-name>
   <var>bundle</var>
</resource-bundle>
```

Your JSF component would be something like:

```
<h:outputText value="#{bundle[myRoles.conversationScope.userRole]}"/>
```